# How to calculate two hours from two times?

Tags: php, time, hour

I have two times like `10:00 am` and `7:00 pm`.

And from this I want to get the total hours. As from that time I have to get the 9 hours.

How will I do this?

I have explode it with the `:` but it then subtract 7 from 10 and return the result 3 which is incorrect because it should return 9.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo  strtotime('7:00 pm')-strtotime('10:00 am');?>
```

Get the timestamp difference

**EDIT**

echo (strtotime('07:00 pm')-strtotime('10:00 am'))/(60*60); //displays 9

60*60 = 1 Hrs

**EDIT**

```
$fromTime = '3:00 pm';
$toTime = '12:00 am';
$timediff   =   (strtotime($toTime)-strtotime($fromTime))/(60*60);
echo $timediff >= 0 ?  $timediff : (24 + $timediff);
```

Comment: But it returns it in timestamp. I want the number 9.

Comment: but with 3:00 pm - 12:00 am it returns 15. which is incorrect.

Comment: @Ahmad Its Correct..[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11] AM   [12 1 2 3] PM  = Total 15 Hrs

Comment: Its not correct. I am calculating the total hours spent in office. SO if office timing is from 3pm to 12am the total duty hours are 9. And it returns 15 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function of PHP to convert this to unix time and so you can do the further calculation with it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can get hold of the `am` or `pm` information! With this information you can make an `if()` to make it correct!

`If()` it is PM, add 12 hours, if it is not PM, don't do anything.

Do this with the times you're comparing:

```
if (pm==1){
time+=12;
}
```

so `10:00 am = false`  it will be 10:00
and `7:00 pm = true`   it will be 19:00

`19:00 - 10:00 = 9 hours = win`.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this will help you out more effectively

```
<?php echo  date('H:i:s',strtotime('7:00 pm')-strtotime('10:00 am'));?>
```

Comment: it also returns 15 when I try to calculate from 3:00pm to 12:00am

Comment: try this......<?php echo  date('h:i:s a',strtotime('3:00 pm')-strtotime('12:00 am'));?>

Comment: sorry for the wrong info....You have to get time diffrenece and then divide the result by 3600 will get you hrs and same way get the minutes......<?php echo  (strtotime('3:00 pm')-strtotime('2:00 pm'))/3600;?>

Answer (score 0):

**Use DateTime interface, Its simple**

```
    $day1= new DateTime("today 01:33:26am");
    $dayd2= new DateTime("today 10:40:36pm");         //Output: Hours: 21
    $interval= $day1->diff($day2);
    $h =  ($interval->days * 24) + $interval->h;
    echo "Hours: ".$h
```

Here 
h = number of hours. 
$interval->days means how many days get from difference if we get one(1) day then it's add 1*24(hours) = 24+21 = 46 hour's but here day1 and day2 contains today so, that's means 0*24 = 0 + 21 = 21

**Finally Output: 21 hour's**